# Central limit theorem. Population with exponential distribution

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

My problem says: Let Y be a random variable with exponential distribution and parameter 1/50, the lifetime of a product in hours. Consider a population of 100 products. Let X be the R.V. that represents the number of products that last over 50 hours. Compute $\Bbb   
 P(X>40)$. If this is supposed to be solved by CLT, then i should be able to see X as the sum of Y's or something similar. I don't know how to put X in terms of the independent identically distributed Ys.

Comment: Let $Y_i$ be $1$ if member $i$ of the population lasts $50$ hours, $0$ otherwise. Then $X$ is the sum of these $Y_i.$

Comment: Observe that $X$ has binomial distribution with parameter $n=100$ and $p=P(Y>50)$ and can be looked at as a summation of $100$ iid rvs with Bernoulli distribution (as indicated by @RagibZaman).

Comment: @drhab do you think that has something to do with the central limit theorem?

Comment: You already exhibited the link with CLT yourself (sum of iid rvs). But also you can go for a direct approximation of binomial distribution with normal distribution.